# How to resolve an "Illegal choice detected " error in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

Drupal is giving me an error message which says : "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator" on the site : http://naplesres.designbracket.com
Whats worse is that this error is preventing me from logging into the website . Each time i input the uname/pwd of any of the users it throws an error.(I have double checked that there is no change in the password by checking at the user table in the database)

The root of the error , I think , lies in the "Find your Local Coupons" block in the left sidebar. This search has been created by exposing the filter of a view and the values in it is what must be leading to the error . However not being able to log into the site in spite of the correct  password is baffling . Kindly help 
THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference:
If a block is causing that problem, try disabling it from the database. Same can be applied to modules causing problems.

You can disable blocks in the 'blocks' table, set status=0 and region=''

Modules are in the 'system' table, just set status=0 to disable it.

They have saved me a lot of time when trying out incomplete modules or even doing something wrong on the ones I code.

Comment: Thanks for this useful tip. Would take care of this .

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve the error. It was more of hit and trial than logic. The toughest part was to log into the website. In spite of repeatedly resetting the password at the database level I wasn't able to login. So I clicked on request new password and used the 1 time login url to log into the site and reset the password.

The main cause of the error lied with the view which was picking values based on a CCK select list. The allowed values in the CCK select list were changed; which i believe caused some conflict . Saving the view again solved the error automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem when simply trying to create a page or block: Drupal would display an "illegal choice - contact administrator" form error. I discovered it was occurring because my install did not include a default "Input Format," and trying to create a new page was failing because of an empty radio button. Once I set it to "Filtered HTML," I stopped getting the error. You can set a default input format by going to Administer > Site Configuration > Input Formats.

Also, double-check your user permissions. For some reason my install did not give full permissions to the admin, so I created a new Administrator role and gave myself full permissions.